# How do I add a tag from the mobile app?

Tags: support, tags, stackexchange-mobile-app

I was going to ask a question from the android app but the tag did not exist and I could not seem to add it.

Any advice on how to do this?

Comment: Related: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5700/what-do-i-do-if-the-mobile-interface-wont-let-me-create-new-tags-and-im-asking

Comment: Related http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/213606/230957

Answer (score 1):

Short of telling the page to give you the full page instead of the mobile page, and then adding the new tag, there's not a way to do it.

The mobile pages, for whatever reason, don't support adding tags that haven't yet been created.

I suspect the app works similarly, as it is lacking many functions of the real site.

Comment: Pretty sure this question refers to the new [mobile app](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/01/stack-exchange-for-android-is-here/) and not just the mobile version of the site. That said, I wouldn't be surprised if it shares the same [meta-tag:status-bydesign] limitations.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that, hence my last sentence. There is also this [meta.SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213606/allow-creating-new-tags) post, so I suspect it is just not possible within the app, as you said.

Comment: Damn you and your edits (which are now INVISIBLE making me look FOOLISH, DAMN YOU GRACE PERIOD) as I was drafting a comment.

Comment: So basically I am a ninja :D